# value in my array changes but i don't know how to find where it is being changed

Tags: angularjs

So, i have this problem where a property in my array collection changes.  Here is the code snippet for my controller:

```
$http({
method: 'GET',
headers: globalData.httpHeader,
params: {
        orderkey:$scope.transaction.orderData.orderkey,
        category:'ViewOrderDetail'},
url: globalData.APIARN+ globalData.StageVariable + globalData.OrderRes
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    if (response.data.errorMessage) {
    swal({
      title: "Ooops!",
      text: "Problem Encountered in the Server.  Please Contact Support."
    });

    } else {
        $scope.itemDetails =response.data.order.orderdetail;
        $scope.items = $scope.itemDetails;
        angular.forEach($scope.itemDetails, function(value, key) {
            $scope.itemKeys.push(value.productKey);
            $scope.itemKey = $scope.itemKeys[$scope.itemKeys.length - 1];
            $scope.itemKey++
            $scope.itemAmountValues.push(value.quantity * value.unitPrice)
        });
    } 

    $scope.calcTotalAndProductAmt();

    $scope.showItem = function(selectedKey){
        $scope.selectedKeyItems = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.itemDetails, function(value, key) {
            if(value.itemKey == selectedKey){

              $scope.selectedKeyItems.push(value)
            }
        });
    }
    console.log("before "  + JSON.stringify($scope.items));
    $timeout(function(){
        console.log("after "  + JSON.stringify($scope.items));
    })

}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.messageText = globalData.ProblemLoad;
    swal({
      title: "Ooops!",
      text: $scope.messageText
    });
}); // $http call
```

Now, the console log result shows the following:

```
before [{"id":95,"productKey":"19","productName":"Roast     Chicken","quantity":2,"unitPrice":175,"itemStatus":"OPEN"},{"id":96,"productKey":"14","productName":"Bolognese","quantity":3,"unitPrice":225,"itemStatus":"OPEN"},{"id":97,"productKey":"16","productName":"Coke","quantity":4,"unitPrice":50,"itemStatus":"CLOSE"},{"id":98,"productKey":"22","productName":"Rice","quantity":2,"unitPrice":45,"itemStatus":"OPEN"}]
transaction.js:1149 
after [{"id":95,"productKey":"19","productName":"Roast Chicken","quantity":2,"unitPrice":175,"itemStatus":"OPEN","$$hashKey":"object:103"},{"id":96,"productKey":"14","productName":"Bolognese","quantity":3,"unitPrice":225,"itemStatus":"OPEN","$$hashKey":"object:104"},{"id":97,"productKey":"16","productName":"Coke","quantity":4,"unitPrice":50,"itemStatus":"OPEN","$$hashKey":"object:105"},{"id":98,"productKey":"22","productName":"Rice","quantity":2,"unitPrice":45,"itemStatus":"OPEN","$$hashKey":"object:106"}]
```

As you can see, the itemStatus for Coke changes from "CLOSED" to "OPEN".  However, i don't know how the value changes since my controller does not have a code that changes this.  My html looks like this:

```
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div class="col col-60" ng-show="item.itemStatus='OPEN'" >
                {{item}}
                <label class="item item-input">
                   <select ng-model="item.productKey" ng-change="addPriceEdit(item)"  ng-required="true">
                  <option  ng-repeat="item in productskey" value="{{item.productkey}}" >{{item.productname}}</option>
                  </select>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-15">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="number" ng-model="item.quantity" min="1" step="1" max="9999999999" ng-required="true" ng-change="calcTotalAndProductAmt()">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-15">
                <label class="item ">
                    {{item.unitPrice}}
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-10">
                <button class="button button-assertive"
                        ng-disabled="item.itemStatus!='OPEN'" 
                        ng-click="removeItem($index)">-</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Anyone has an idea on what's wrong?

Comment: update:  If I remove the  ng-show="item.itemStatus='OPEN'" from the second line of the html, the value does not change.  Weird, is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with -

```
<div class="col col-60" ng-show="item.itemStatus=='OPEN'" >
```

Because , with single = , you are assigning value to the variable(so for each object it will change itemstatus to open) . For comparing  , you should use ==.

Comment: i am actually comparing the value of item.itemStatus to "OPEN" - not assigning it.

Comment: sorry, i see what you mean.  I'll try that.